# How to define array/collection in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a fixed array of strings on which I want to operate. How should I declare them in stored procedure? Is it even possible?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testing AS

BEGIN

operations...
END;
```

Can we declare like DECLARE @v1 varchar(15); or something similar for collection of string?(PS "@" throwing error on Oracle SQL Developer )

A newbie in SQL, so expecting a sample code if possible thanks.

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS005) is a good starting point

Comment: you can use varray(Plsql Tables). Go through it https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm

Comment: check this example [PL/SQL - Arrays](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_arrays.htm) it may helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
declare
   type array_t is varray(3) of varchar2(2);
   array array_t := array_t('aa', 'bb', 'cc');
begin
   for i in 1..array.count loop
       dbms_output.put_line(array(i));
   end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Hii, if i want to access month array like, `months[] = '01-01-2020,01-02-2020,01-03-2020';` and access each element. how to do it.